# ReactJS loading component from string

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I am using Chakraui library for reactjs

I am saving the string version of the code into a database, then retrieving it and rendering to user. For demo I assign it to a variable. When I try to render it, it doesn't apply the component `<Code/>` which formats the text

```
const test = `text text <Code>text</Code>`;

 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: test }} />
```